# Create a command for a different font

Tags: macros, emphasis

I'm pretty new to Latex and I am writing my thesis. I would like to use a command that I can essentially change the font of a few words in-line or separate (like an equation).

I have computer commands that I would like to display in a different font (Courier New) than the rest of the document. I have heard that I could either modify the `\emph{}` command or create a new command like `\comp{}` that changes the font.

I don't know how to do either. Is there a package that already does this for me? Thanks for your help

Example:

```
Next you need to position the robot arm by using the command \comp{Home}.
```

OR

```
\comp{cd folder ./trajectory.exe}
```

Comment: There is a package for that --> `\listings`. read its manula by typing `texdoc listings` from terminal

Comment: For just a word inline, though, `\texttt{}`? Whoever suggested you redefine `\emph{}` gave you extremely bad advice. Don't. Welcome to TeX SE, by the way!

Comment: My suggestion would be to add `\usepackage{listings} \lstsetup{basicstyle=\ttfamily} \let\comp\lstinline` to your preamble.

Comment: You might find this to be a fairly handy rundown on some of the ways to have LaTeX typeset code: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_listing

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a macro. Wikibooks has excellent [tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros) on the topic. As for the code environment, use the `listings` package: [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings), [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/).

Here is a quick example of what you can do. The `\newcommand`s there make three, well, new commands: `\compbox`, `\compline`, and `\comp`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
language=Python,%
basicstyle=\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\ttfamily,%
numbers = left,
numberstyle = \tiny,
numbersep = 5pt,
} %% Many other options!

\newcommand{\compbox}[1]{\ovalbox{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\compline}[1]{\underline{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\comp}[1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Hit the \compbox{F5} key. Next you need to position the
robot arm by using the command \compline{Home}. Now run
this on the terminal:

 \comp{texdoc listings}

Which should open \comp{listings} documentation.
Then you can write something like this:

\begin{lstlisting}
import math
import sys
def cube(x):
    return x*x*x
# An example of Python code
# in LaTeX
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I'm afraid the tutorial is not so excellent: the second example of `\newcommand` has a very bad error (missing `%` after the open brace). It may seem pedantry, but it isn't, as several questions on this site about this prove. The first example of `\newenvironment` goes even beyond this adding nefarious spaces on purpose! And the `%` that protect the end-of-lines in the examples of `\newenvironment{simple}` and `\newenvironment{correct}` are ridiculous (they are completely innocuous and useless).

Comment: @egreg. Yes, that is rather sad. I hope that tutorial's author is also on this site and read your comment!